# Rows to column conversion of file

Tags: awk, sed, text-formatting

Suppose I have a file:

File1:

```
PAPER  TEAM  MANISH NISHA GARIMA JYOUTI ........etc
```

File2 I want:

```
PAPER    
TEAM
MANISH
NISHA
GARIMA    
JYOUTI
```

Rows to column conversion of File1.

Comment: If your file consists of more than one line and your output should thus have more than one column, then try [this AWK script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1729980/26428).

Comment: Very much related question: http://askubuntu.com/q/461144/295286

Answer (score 31):

Using `tr`, replace each repeated space character( ) with a single new-line(`\n`) character.

```bsh
tr -s ' '  '\n'< infile > outfile
```

---

**But I think you want something like this?**

| Original | Transposed |
| --- | --- |
| ``` 0 1 2 3 a b c d # $ @ % ``` | ``` 0 a # 1 b $ 2 c @ 3 d % ``` |

With `awk` we could do:

```bsh
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) RtoC[i]= (i in RtoC?RtoC[i] OFS :"") $i; } 
    END{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print RtoC[i] }' infile
```

This joins each same filed number positon into together and in `END` prints the result that would be first row in first column , second row in second column, etc. Of course the input file is limited to your memory size.

Answer (score 13):

You could also use the `fmt` command:

```
~$ cat f
PAPER  TEAM  MANISH NISHA GARIMA JYOUTI
~$ fmt -1 f
PAPER
TEAM
MANISH
NISHA
GARIMA
JYOUTI
```

Answer (score 11):

With [GNU datamash](http://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
$ datamash -W transpose <file
PAPER
TEAM
MANISH
NISHA
GARIMA
JYOUTI
```

Comment: `datamash` seems like the best tool for the task, but fascinating how many other tools could be used!

Answer (score 10):

You could simply do this through grep. By default grep, would print the match in a separate newline .

```
grep -oP '\S+' infile > outfile
```

OR

```
grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `awk`, setting the output field separator (`OFS`) as the record (line) separator (`RS`):

```
awk '{OFS=RS;$1=$1}1' file > file2
```

Comment: That would set `OFS` to `RS` every time a line is read, you don't need to do that as it's inefficient, doing it once is enough - `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=ORS} {$1=$1}1'`. I also changed RS to ORS as it is technically the output record separator you want to use, only really matters if they're different.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do this using `sed`:

```
$ sed -e 's/  */\n/g' file1 > file2
```

**NOTE:** Doesn't handle the situation where the words contain spaces.

Comment: This requires GNU sed, as best as I can tell. The one that ships with mac (BSD) doesn't see `\n` as newline

Answer (score 1):

Using a `for` loop:

```
for val in `cat file1` ; do echo $val >> file2; done;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=$i"\n"}}1' file1 >file2
```

output

```
PAPER
 TEAM
 MANISH
 NISHA
 GARIMA
 JYOUTI
```

Second method

```
perl -pne "s/ /\n/g" file1 >file2

output

PAPER
TEAM
MANISH
NISHA
GARIMA
JYOUTI
```

Comment: Extra spaces get translated to blank lines using your Perl5 code; I think you mean `s/\s+/\n/g` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne '.put for .words;'
```

Sample Input:

```
PAPER  TEAM  MANISH NISHA GARIMA JYOUTI
paper  team  manish nisha garima jyouti
```

Sample Output:

```
PAPER
TEAM
MANISH
NISHA
GARIMA
JYOUTI
paper
team
manish
nisha
garima
jyouti
```

Note, there seems to be some discussion that the OP doesn't want a single column as output, i.e. that this is actually a row/column transpose question. No matter, below is how you transpose whitespace-separated "columns" in Raku (e.g. capitalized first Row becomes capitalized first Column):

```perl
~$ raku -e '.put for [Z] lines.map(*.words);'  file
PAPER paper
TEAM team
MANISH manish
NISHA nisha
GARIMA garima
JYOUTI jyouti
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using `sed`

```
$ sed -i.bak s@' '@'\n'@g infile.txt
```

Please note that I am using `@` as a separator for the substitution operation.
This will also create a backup file. In case you don't need a backup remove .bak

```
$ sed -i s@' '@'\n'@g infile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Python version:

```
python -c "import sys;lines=[l.replace(' ','\n') for l in sys.stdin.readlines()];print(''.join(lines))" < input.txt > output.txt
```

This uses `<` redirection into python's stdin from `input.txt` and writes to `output.txt` using `>` redirection. The one-liner itself reads in all lines from `stdin` into a list of strings,where all spaces are replaced with newlines, and we rebuild whole text using `.join()` function.

Alternative approach to avoid multiple spaces in series being replaced with newlines is to use `.split()` to break line into list of words. That way , we can ensure that each word is separated only by one newline

```
python -c "import sys;lines=['\n'.join(l.strip().split()) for l in sys.stdin.readlines()];print('\n'.join(lines))" < input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `xargs`, (stolen from [souravc's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/461154/561230)):

```
xargs -n 1 < File1 > File2
```

Or if any minor reformatting is needed, use `printf` format strings as however might be needed:

```
xargs printf '%s\n' < File1 > File2
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
cols=$(head -1 file.txt | wc -w)
for i in $(seq 1 $cols); do
cut -d ' ' -f$i file.txt | tr '\n' ' ' | sed s'/.$//'
echo
done
```

Answer (score -2):

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print($i)}}' file > File2
```