# Add row values of file1 to column headers of file2

Tags: awk, sed

I want to do the opposite of what was done here: [Rows to column conversion of file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169995/rows-to-column-conversion-of-file)

File1

```
MT
MT
MT
GROUP1
GROUP1
GROUP2
```

File2

```
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Outputfile

```
MT MT MT GROUP1 GROUP1 GROUP2 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, using Awk:

```
awk '{$1=$1} 1' RS= File1 RS='\n' File2
MT MT MT GROUP1 GROUP1 GROUP2
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

- read `File1` in paragraph mode by unsetting the record separator
- then reset the default record separator before reading `File2`
- action `$1=$1` causes both files to be re-written with the default output field separator