# Convert text file into CSV file in shell script after manipulation of data

Tags: text-processing

Inside the shell script, one SQL query getting result set and export into **abc.txt** then after DML operation (**INSERTION**) perform & then result set of this statement export into **xyz.txt**. I want to convert all text into one file and then convert into CSV file.

**abc.txt** contained ->

```
ID    desc    before_cnts
01    abnd     112
02    bghs     115
03    ghjjk    119
04    tuhj     123
..    .....    ....
```

**xyz.txt** contained ->

```
ID   after_cnts
01   115
02   119
03   124
04   129
..   ...
```

When i merge both the file & manipulate the values then after got wrong values. But I want **output.txt** file like ->

```
ID  desc   before_cnts   after_cnts
01  abnd   112           115
02  bghs   115           119
03  ghjjk  119           124
04  tuhj   123           129
..  ....   ....          ....
```

Then after i will convert into CSV file. Could you please help to get proper output. Refer [question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554380/transpose-rows-into-columns-into-the-proper-format/554466#554466)

Answer (score 2):

This is what `join` is for:

```
$ join abc.txt xyz.txt
ID desc before_cnts after_cnts
01 abnd 112 115
02 bghs 115 119
03 ghjjk 119 124
04 tuhj 123 129
```

Or, if you also want them visually aligned:

```
$ join abc.txt xyz.txt | column -t
ID  desc   before_cnts  after_cnts
01  abnd   112          115
02  bghs   115          119
03  ghjjk  119          124
04  tuhj   123          129
```