# How to force Dialog to write checklist selections onto sperate lines in a variable

Tags: variable, dialog

I am using the below code to present users with a menu for them to select which software they would like to install.  I then want to use the selections as function calls to perform the installs.

```
OPTIONS=$(dialog --no-tags --clear --backtitle "Installer Options..." --title "Software Selection" \
    --checklist "Use SPACE to select/deselct options and OK when finished."  30 100 30 \
       install_software_a "Install software A" off \
       install_software_b "Install software B" off \
       install_software_c "Install software C" off 2>&1 > /dev/tty)
$OPTIONS
```

The code works well for capturing the selections.  The issue that I am having is that it writes the selections onto a single line, like below if the first two are selected:

```
install_software_a install_software_b
```

When the call is made to $OPTIONS, it is only installing the first software selected.  Is there a way I can format the OPTIONS variable to have the selections written on separate lines like below:

```
install_software_a
install_software_b
```

TIA!

John

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rows to column conversion of file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169995/rows-to-column-conversion-of-file)

Comment: no, the suggested duplicate is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `awk` version which supports multi-character record separators (should work on most recent implementations of `awk`), you can use the following call to transpose the data:

```
echo "$options" | awk -v RS="[ \n]" '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the output to a file, using the option `--stdout`, and then `cat` the file:

```
dialog --stdout --no-tags --clear --backtitle "Installer Options..." --title "Software Selection" \
    --checklist "Use SPACE to select/deselct options and OK when finished."  30 100 30 \
       install_software_a "Install software A" off \
       install_software_b "Install software B" off \
       install_software_c "Install software C" off \
 > file

OPTIONS=$(cat file | tr -s ' ' '\n')

echo "${OPTIONS[@]}"

install_software_a
install_software_b
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **`--separate-output`** option of dialog (i.e., before the **`--checklist`** option).  In the [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html):

> **`--separate-output`**
>
> For certain widgets (*buildlist*, ***checklist***, *treeview*), output result  one  line  at  a  time, with no quoting.  This facilitates
> parsing by another program.